# VSTO Microsoft Project 2010. Create a CustomField with a lookup list?

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I've an addin for microsoft project that loads data into a microsoft project sheet.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a customfield in VS with a lookup list.

This is how you do it in microsoft project: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZML9IyoPY7Y (dropdownlist)

But I want my code to do it for me. So when I press on the load button in my addin it should automatically create the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution for it. After some headbanging.

```
myproject.Application.CustomFieldRename(PjCustomField.pjCustomTaskText12, "columnName");                       
myproject.Application.CustomFieldPropertiesEx(PjCustomField.pjCustomTaskText12, PjCustomFieldAttribute.pjFieldAttributeValueList);
myproject.Application.CustomFieldValueListAdd(PjCustomField.pjCustomTaskText12, "ListValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

This link [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms453877%28v=office.12%29.aspx) about working with Local Custom Fields and Lookup Tables from UI and VBA. This article is for Project 2007, but VBA wasn't change since that time.

Here is a [reference to LookupTable from Project 2010 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff920625%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

And also there is no too much difference between VBA and C#, if you plan to use VSTO Add-In. The only thing about C#: don't forget to release any reference to COM explicitly using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` Garbage Collector does not free these kind of resources.

Comment: Yeah, tried LookupTable but I didnt figure out how it worked. But I found another solution for my problem. Thanks anyways!